# Allow users to add item to the list but not view

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-server

I have a custom SharePoint list called "Feedback" and I customized this list form in infopath and I published to this list. Also I have added a link in the homepage say "Submit Your Feedback". All the users submit their feedback by clicking on this link. All the feedbacks are saved into Feedback list. We need to allow all the users to submit their feedback through "Submit Your Feedback" link.

Now, we want to restrict all the users to submit the feedback but not view all the feedbacks in the "Feedback" list. Also we need to allow 4 users to see all the feedbacks in the list.

We are not supposed to use Visual studio. Is there any way that I can handle this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Create view and add filter in view such that current user sees always his/her items.Now set this newly created view to default view on list.Essentially it should be createdby = [ME].I think then only your current user will only see his/her items.Give permission to this users in such a way so that they cannot switch views.and give all permissions to rest of 4 users .

Answer (score 10):

I think essentially what you want is a combination of these two things (found under List Settings > Advanced Settings);

[image]

This allows users to only view **and** only edit their **own** records/entries in the list.

**EDIT:** As discussed in comments below, you will also need to grant your 4 users "Cancel Checkout" permissions for them to be able to see all records/entries.

Comment: This will not satisfy requirement: "we need to allow 4 users to see all the feedbacks in the list".

Comment: Read the note in the image. "Users with the Cancel Checkout permission can read and edit all items". Grant those 4 users that permission.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I just pointed out that your answer does not describe all the necessary steps to satisfy all the requirements.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to do this via the rest api?

Answer (score 1):

you can get this with little effort.

- create a new permission level( copy the read permission)
- modify this new permisions level
- unchecking View Items checkbox under List settings.
- Checking Add Items checkbox under List Settings.

Now

- You can break inheritance( if you want only allow add access and only
  4 user with view)
- on list permission settings, apply the new permission level to user
  or Group.
- Now add the 4 super user with required level of permission.

Comment: Waqas, Thanks for your reply. I have added new permission level. If I check Add items check box it will automatically select View items check box. How can I do this? Please reply...

Comment: This answer doesn't work because View and Add cannot be separated.

Comment: SharePoint UI forces 'View items' permissions when you add 'Add items', but it is possible to create this permission level using PowerShell or code.

Answer (score 0):

Waqas' answer is perfect, and you can get around the "checking one box checks the other" issue by unchecking both, going into developer mode in chrome and deleting the view items checkbox element, so when you check the "add items" checkbox, it can't check the view items checkbox via javascript.  It does no server side checking for validation, only client-side.